# About definition of weak derivative in abstract PDE problems

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I'm confused about weak derivative definition.

$u \in L^2(0,T;V)$ has weak derivative $u'\in L^2(0,T;V')$ iff

$$\int_0^T u(t)\varphi'(t) = -\int_0^T u'(t)\varphi(t)$$

holds for all $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(0,T).$

The LHS is an object in $V$. What is the RHS? Should the integrand be $\langle u'(t), \varphi(t) \rangle_{V',V}$ (**edit**: I guess not)? If so then it is a real number. If not, it is in $V'$.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: This question belongs in math.stackexchange.com and not here.

Comment: @DeaneYang I read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250690/distributional-weak-time-derivative-basic-question and I have read conflicting statements on MSE so it seemed better to ask it here :|

Comment: I've posted an answer on MSE.

Comment: Hi @AaronHoffman my test functions are real-valued. I disagree that it will be $V$-valued (unless it lies in that stronger space). Please see Definition 5.7 here, http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZYAW5D8xI1MC&pg=PA94&dq=parabolic+weak+time+derivative&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n_h7Ub26M8j70gWP3YHQDQ&ved=0CEgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=parabolic%20weak%20time%20derivative&f=false, which i believe answered my doubts. I would say that both integrals will be $V*$ valued. 

Comment: @DeaneYang thank you for your answer. But why restrict the derivative $u'(t)$ to lie in such a strong space? $H^{-1}$ is better and seems more widely used. As I understand it now (after reading the book I linked to above), $u'(t)\varphi(t)$ makes sense because you're just multiplying an element of $V^*$ by some real-valued function, so no problems. It's not the dual pairing in this case.

Comment: It seems to me that you get the same answer, whether you make $\phi$ real-valued or $V'$-valued. The only thing that changes is whether the two integrals are real-valued (if $\phi$ is $V'$-valued) or $V$-valued (if $\phi$ is real-valued). Note that whatever you do has to be consistent with what you get if $u$ and $\phi$ are smooth functions of $t$. Also, the weak derivative with with respect to the same co-ordinate or variable that you integrate by parts with. Here, that's $t$.

Comment: And this discussion really should be taking place on MSE. This is *not* a research-level question.